# OpenID identifier active session

Tags: openid

I have this http://localhost:8080/jos-webapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT/bicho like my identifier in an OpenId server

In the client I have this:

```
  <form method="get" action="try_auth.php">
        identifier <input type="text" name="openid_identifier" value="" />
         <submit/>
  </form>
```

My question is, If I want to login into website client , how can I get the login form from Server without put the specific openid_identifier (http://local.../bicho ) , and once do that return to my website client?

So, if I have a session active in openId server how can I get this session from a client?...

I'm trying with [Openid-Sever](http://openid-server.googlecode.com) like a server and
 [php-openid](https://nodeload.github.com/openid/php-openid/zipball/2.2.2)  like client